# onBeforeSaveEntry is hanging on import

Tags: entries, saveentry

I am using the [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) plugin. This question doesn't have to do with the Import plugin which seems to be working swell, but instead with my `onBeforeSaveEntry` logic which seems to have botched the import process.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event)
    {

        if($params['isNewEntry']) {

            $entry = $event->params['entry'];

            $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
            $criteria->groupId = 1;
            $criteria->AffiliateId = $entry['AffiliateId']; 
            $criteria->limit = 1;
            $users = $criteria->find();

            if (!empty($users)) {           
                $assignedCoach = $users[0]->id;
                $entry->authorId = $assignedCoach;
                $entry->getContent()->coachId = $assignedCoach;
            }
        }        
    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, any idea how I kill the import processes which seem to be hung at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script probably chokes because you're interacting with an undeclared variable `$params` – i.e. change

```
if($params['isNewEntry']) {
```

to

```
if($event->params['isNewEntry']) {
```

Comment: That seems to be working, but now now the following line is not working. $entry->authorId = $assignedCoach; while $entry->getContent()->coachId = $assignedCoach; is working fine.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer to the last question I had on this thread regarding authorId here > http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/use-onbeforesaveentry-event-to-update-entrymodel-properties