# Updating the postDate field from a plugin?

Tags: plugins, postdate, onsaveentry

I think I'm almost there with this one but obviously missing something as the postDate is not updating. I have the following in an onSaveEntry event. It's saying it's successful but the postDate does not change. Ideally I want this to update whether the entry is enabled or not.

```
public function onSaveEntry(Event $event)
{
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    // set postDate from assignedDate
    if($user->admin) {
        if($entry->assignedDate && $entry->assignedTimeslot) {
            $timeslot = $entry->assignedDate.' '.$entry->assignedTimeslot.'.000000';
            $params = $entry->postDate = $timeslot;
            $success = craft()->elements->saveElement($entry, $params);
        }
    }
    return $event;
}
```

Comment: I would try using a single field on the entry called `assignedDateTime` which can take a date and a time. This can then be used to set the postDate. Why has the timeslot got `'.00000'` after it?

Comment: @LukePearce just something I added after a bit of googling. But didn't work. Doesn't work when removed either.

Comment: @LukePearce sorry correction on that as well as Googling I picked it up from the object postDate returns.

Answer (score 4):

`$timeslot` isn't formatted correctly to be used as the postDate. I'd create a field that takes a date and a time and then use `DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb()` to format for use as `postDate`.

You can't modify the `postDate` until after the entry has been saved - so will need to resave the entry with the newly set `postDate`. More info as to why you have to do this [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/%E2%80%A6).

```
craft()->on( 'entries.onSaveEntry', function( Event $event ){

  // Grab the entry from post request
  $entry = $event->params['entry'];

  // Get logged in user
  $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

  if ( $user && $user->admin ) {
    $timeSlot = $entry->getContent()->assignedTimeslot;

    // If the postDate and Timeslot don't match (stops infinite loop)
    if ( !( $entry->postDate == $timeSlot ) ) {

        // Set postDate to timeSlot date
        $entry->postDate = DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb( $timeSlot );

        // Resave entry
        craft()->entries->saveEntry( $entry );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the `$timeslot` variable is set to `2016-11-10 14:00:00` and if I `print_r` the `$entry->postDate` it returns an object `Craft\DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-11-10 14:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )` So looks like it is formatted correctly. Any further clues?

Comment: So I've updated the logic with `DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb()` this ensures the formats match. I've tested locally and this is working for me. Give it a go.

Comment: Not sure calling `saveEntry` inside of an `onSaveEntry` event is correct? The code hangs for me. Is that not setting up an infinite loop? Also the date is made up of 2 variables `assignedDate` and `assignedTimeslot` so you are only assigning the time to the `DateTimeHelper` without the date part.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. My suggestion was to combine your `assignedDate` field with you `assignedTimeslot` field. What fieldtype are these currently set up with? Unfortunately I don't think the postDate is accessible `onSaveEntry`. I've also tried with `beforeOnSaveEntry` and can set other custom field values but not the `postDate`.

Comment: More info : http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/use-onbeforesaveentry-event-to-update-entrymodel-properties

Comment: cheers Luke. It still didn't work for me as the code was still hanging trying to re-save the entry within the `onSaveEntry` but you got me on the right track. I re-jigged the code a little with the conditionals so it set the `postDate` check outside of the user check. I also created a new DateTime object as the check was failing. I guess it needs to check object against object. But now it works a treat. I will add final code as the answer. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Was it hanging when creating a new entry? Might need some more conditionals for `isNewEntry` or not.

Comment: No on existing entries as well.

Comment: It would have worked if `assignedTimeslot` was a date/time field.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @LukePearce I managed to re-write the code to work as follows:

```
craft()->on( 'entries.onSaveEntry', function( Event $event ){

  // Grab the entry from post request
  $entry = $event->params['entry'];

  // Get logged in user
  $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

  // Set the timeslot
  $timeSlot = $entry->getContent()->assignedDate.' '.$entry->getContent()->assignedTimeslot;

  // Create a new dateTime object from timeslot
  $postDate = new \DateTime($timeSlot);

  // Check the postDate has changed
  if ($entry->postDate != $postDate) {

    // check user is set and is admin
    if ($user && $user->admin) {

      // Set entry postDate to new postDate
      $entry->postDate = $postDate;

      // Resave entry
      $success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);

    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a plugin for this exact use case. You can configure what time is set as the postDate or expiryDate via a Twig template.

https://github.com/carlcs/craft-autoexpire